# Find the mistake in the following proof by induction (exercise in AOC, Vol.1, Knuth)

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

In the Art Of Programming by Knuth there is the following exercise:

> There must be something wrong with the following proof. What is it? "**Theorem**. Let $a$ be any positive number. For all positive integers $n$ we have $a^{n-1} = 1$. *Proof.* If $n=1$, $a^{n-1} = a^{1-1} = a^{0} = 1$. And by induction, assuming that the theorem is true for $n=1,...,n$, we have $$a^{(n+1)-1} = a^{n} = \frac{a^{n-1}\times a^{n-1}}{a^{(n-1)-1}}=\frac{1\times 1}{1}=1;$$
>   So the theorem is true for $n+1$ as well.

And the corresponding answer:

> The theorem has not been proved for $n=2$. In the second part of the proof take $n=1$. We assume there that $a^{(n-1)-1}=a^{-1}=1$.[...]

The problem is I don't understand the answer. Why Knuth highlights number 2 here? With the same success one could have said: "the theorem has not been proved for $n=1729$". And this doesn't seem to me as a good way to decline proof by induction because (to me) such a proof doesn't deal with concrete numbers but the base. I think the real mistake with the above proof is simply the third equality. It must be:
$$\frac{a^{n-1}\times a^{n-1}}{a^{(n-1)-1}}=\frac{1\times 1}{1\times a^{-1}}=a$$ And from that we cannot conclude that it equals one.
I think that the original answer confuses a reader. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your explaination does not answer the question because the erroneous statement assumes that $a^{(n-1)-1}=1$ so the computations are correct ; it is the assumption that is false.

Comment: @häxq, the key moment is why one assumes that $a^{(n-1)-1} = 1$. Where it comes from?

Comment: He assumes that the theorem holds up to $n$ so in particular, that it holds for $(n-1)-1 = n-2$.

Comment: @häxq OK. Got it. But I think it is better to leave $(n-1) - 1$ because it stands for $P(n-1)$. I am trying to understand the whole thing now.

Comment: Sorry fo beginner question.

For the P(n+1) "proof" why does a^n equal a^(n-1) * a^(n-1) / a^(n-1)-1 . Is that step an arbitrary conversion or does it come from somewhere?

Comment: @HéctorGarcía, It comes from the rules which powers adhere to: If $a\neq 0$ then a) $a^{m} a^{n} = a^{m+n}$, b) $a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying and I still can't figure out how a^n=a^(n-1) * a^(n-1) / a^(n-1)-1 by using the basic power rules a) and b) that you explained to me. For example, how can I get a^(n-1)-1 in the denominator if I have a^n? (n is positive)

Comment: I don't know (I know it's not) if this is the right place for the discussion but anyway I think it will be removed so here is how it goes: $a^{n-1} a^{n-1} = a^{2n-2}$ (rule a), $\frac{1}{a^{(n-1)-1}} = a^{-n+2}$ (rule b), $a^{2n-2}a^{-n+2} = a^{n}$ (rule a).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what happens when you go from $n=1$ to $n=2$. The argument breaks down because  you will get $a^{0-1}$ in the denominator. When you go from $n$ to  $n+1$ you  have to make sure that the argument works for any positive integer $n$. In this case it fails for $n=1$. That is why the case $n=2$ creates a problem.

Comment: First of all, it doesn't fail for $n=1$. Second of all, why should I care some specific number to see whether proof by induction is correct. I should care only two steps: a) Proof that $P(0)$ is true, and b) Proof that if $\forall k: 0\leq k < n, P(k)$ is true then $P(n)$ also true. In this case induction step b) fails.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I am not saying that $P(1)$ fails. The argument in part b) fails when $n=2$. Go through the proof of b) and see what happens to $P(1)$ implying $P(2)$. That is where the trouble is. @LRDPRDX

Comment: OK. I understand what you mean: I see that $P(n+1)$ depends on $P(n)$ AND $P(n-1)$. But I am allowed to use only $P(k), k>0$ (because the base is $P(1)$) so I am not allowed to use the induction step for $n=1$ which is responsible for $P(2)$ so I must proof $P(2)$ separately.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. The strategy for proof by induction is to express $P(n+1)$ as $f(P(n), P(n-1), ..., P(n-k))$ where $P(0)$ is the base and check "by hand" cases $P(0), P(1), ..., P(k)$ ?

Comment: @LRDPRDX Yes, that is correct.

Comment: OK, thank you. They should add this rule explicitly I think.